# How did the Ministry not catch the trio in Deathly Hallows?

Tags: harry-potter, apparition

Given that

- The Ministry keeps tabs on people Apparating (according to JKR, interview quoted [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/170647/78225)),

and that

- the Death Eaters controlled the Ministry after the death of Rufus Scrimgeour in Book 7

**how did the trio manage to travel by apparating from one place to another and not get caught?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As quoted in the accepted answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10270/can-apparition-be-traced?noredirect=1&lq=1):

> "It's impossible to track anyone who Apparates, unless you grab hold of them as they disappear."
>
> <sub>-Remus Lupin - Deathly Hallows - Chapter 11 - The Bribe</sub>

So the Ministry may have been able to detect that Harry and co had Disapparated from location X, but they'd have no idea where they had actually Apparated to.